# Napier's devilry

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, printers-devilry

> [image]

**Note:** The clues are a mix of printer's devilry and regular cryptic clues.

> **Across**
>   2. Like Bruce Wayne after Jack Napier's constant plots essentially destroyed city (7)
>   7. Group known for Africa's total leader in oil (4)
>   8. Estonia and late tin asylum seekers (4)
>   9. Country next to France's (and/or Romania's) borders (7)
>   10. Achievement coming before in Georgia (4)
>   12. Female John Travolta character (*Leaving Las Vegas*) (4)
>   15. Homer described Odysseus' pic poem (5)
>   18. Religion's central part of worship in North African country, as seen from the east (5)
>   19. Trainings see earning process (5)
>   20. Android: extremely competent to adjust to different situations (5)
>   21. Italian leader abandoned shaving, leading to an affair (5)
>   22. Wikipedia's content WA sensed to be available under CC-BY-SA (5)
>   23. Some sour Cher – husband left her (5)
>   26. Nonexistent East River (4)
>   29. A sign of a fictional captain going the wrong way (4)
>   31. Trade ad panned essentially for being delivered with straight face (7)
>   32. Neighbour of Oscar's father (4)
>   33. Tango partner for musician Johnny (4)
>   34. A Mediterranean meal set up (7)
>
> **Down**
>   1. A fish with a tail? (4)
>   2. Jack and Oscar standing by a last member of Clan Crawford (4)
>   3. NORAD processed radioactive gas (5)
>   4. Mark Blixen on the radio (5)
>   5. So valuable sample round (4)
>   6. American football players Garrett and Benatar (4)
>   10. Legendary creature's smile interrupted by flipping off (7)
>   11. Although he's called Bi, Ami's his real name (3-4)
>   13. David's son essentially stabs a Lombard (7)
>   14. Element of South Dakota's state symbol (7)
>   15. The heroes clam as a reward (5)
>   16. President Saddam devastated after having democratic leader removed (5)
>   17. Guard blocking second entrance (5)
>   24. He was considered the be-around player in the NBA (5)
>   25. Application by the French tech company (5)
>   27. Religious leader: "I am a man" (4)
>   28. Cheese produced in lift (4)
>   29. Tourist, inform a tinter (4)
>   30. His ramblings became more in anime passed (4)

Comment: 14-Down is very clever!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

Thoughts:

> I'm still not sure how exactly 7-A, 12-A, and 22-D work.
>
>  Clues 1-D and 14-D were very clever! 14-D especially so -- the wordplay in had to be parsed *completely* differently from how it appeared.
>
>  Not sure about the grammar in 10A (I think a comma would be necessary?), and 17D's definition seems to be fairly similar to the answer. Other than that, the clues were in general pretty good.

Comment: 12A: rot13(YNF(-irtn)F)

Comment: Nice work! For 22 across, the answer is correct but you need to slightly move the place where it's inserted.

Comment: 7a could be rot13(GBG sbe Gbgny, + B)

Comment: (i just noticed Jafe already alluded to this above, but anyway:) 22 across should be "was relicensed" :0